how to fetch data from dynamic graph in python
I am trying to fetch data from a dynamic line graph at this website: https://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=SGD&to=USD&view=5Y.
You can change time periods in the website, but all network requests are made when the page loads for the first time and when the time period is changed, the only network requests made are for the data under the graph.
In the network tab, one of the only links that I found that fetches somewhat similar data was: https://www.xe.com/api/protected/charting-rates/?fromCurrency=SGD&toCurrency=USD&crypto=true
But when I checked the generated excel file, the data points it shows were never part of the graph.
This is the script
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import requests
import pandas as pd
import os
BASE_DIR =os.getcwd()
url="https://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=SGD&to=USD&view=5Y"
data_url = "https://www.xe.com/api/protected/charting-rates/?fromCurrency=SGD&toCurrency=USD&crypto=true"

headers = {'authorization': 'Basic bG9kZXN0YXI6cHVnc25heA=='}
response = requests.get(data_url, headers=headers) 
if response.status_code == 200:
    try:
        # Parse the response JSON content
        response_data = response.json()
        timestamp = response_data.get('timestamp') / 1000

        # Convert to human-readable date
        converted_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
        data_list = response_data.get('batchList')
        values_list = []
        for data_item in data_list:
            start_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(data_item.get('startTime')/1000)
            interval = timedelta(data_item.get('interval')/1000)
            for rate in data_item.get('rates'):
                values_list.append({'Timestamp' : converted_date,'Start Time': start_time, 'Interval' :interval , 'Rate' : rate})
        
        df = pd.DataFrame(values_list)
        excel_file_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'SGDToUSD.csv')
        df.to_csv(excel_file_path, index=False)
        print("Data saved to Excel File")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: " , e)
else:
    print(f"Request failed with status code {response.status_code}")

I have tried loading the page with selenium and using mouse hover to fetch the data points but that didn't work either.
Is there any way with or without selenium that I can fetch this data ?

Hey I saw that web page using the isExtended=true parameter when the graph year is ["2Y","5Y","10Y"] (i saw view=5Y parameter in your URL)
Here is the javascript code that defines the logic (javascript URL:https://www.xe.com/_next/static/chunks/currency-chart.059515297ffaf125.js):
ep = ["2Y", "5Y", "10Y"].includes(ei), [ex, ey] = (0, n.useState)(ep);
(0, n.useEffect)(() => {
    ep && ey(!0)
}, [ep]);
let {
    data: eg,
    error: eb
} = (0, b.ZP)(ex ? "/api/protected/charting-rates/?fromCurrency=".concat(r, "&toCurrency=").concat(i, "&isExtended=true") : null, {
    onLoadingSlow: () => G(!0),
    revalidateOnFocus: !1
});

So you have to use the isExtended=true parameter in your target API URL: https://www.xe.com/api/protected/charting-rates/ instead of crypto=true
I think this will solve your problem.

I have seen the url : https://www.xe.com/api/protected/charting-rates/?fromCurrency=SGD&toCurrency=USD&isExtended=true
in the network tab as well, but the issue is, when I go to batchList and then rates in  the response, it includes values that aren't part of the graph.
